# 2 layer board design and grounding

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I am using EAGLE and have a 2layer pcb design. I have signals on both sides and ground on both sides of the board.
I am not able to connect my THS4509 opamps thermal pad (which is the opamps ground) to my pcbs ground. The thermal pad has its own isle.
I can't route the thermal pad to ground because the pins are too close to each other.

The thermal pad is pad17 I need to somehow connect it to the ground polygon. But there is no room.

[image]
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: screenshot?  either change the pcb tools constraints or consider using a 0R resistor as a jumper

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot. I don't know how a jumper would help

Comment: With a via to the bottom plane? Also what is `N$22`, do you work with negative voltages too? I don't get why you have 2 traces going away in different directions.

Comment: Yes it has a positive and negative rail

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your layout but.. can't you just add a via to the bottom layer? Might not be ideal for large runs but for prototypes its fine.

Comment: Yes this should be possible. And probably the best solution. Thanks

Comment: Hi @electrococuk - I have rolled-back to the version before you removed the PCB layout image. Removing important information is only allowed in a few situations (e.g. login information included by mistake) and those usually requires moderator agreement / attention. There's no point in trying to keep the image secret because *Andy aka* has put it in an answer, it's available in the version history of the question, and if you remove it then some comments above make no sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really start off any two layer design with the intention that the bottom side is reserved for ground and that the ground plane might occasionally need to be interrupted (now and then and minimally) by signal and power tracks that need to cross each other. It sounds to me that you may not have started with this sensible intention/philosophy.

If it means ripping up and starting from an earlier point then this is likely to be better in the long run (all things considered) in my opinion. As for the thermal pad what's wrong with placing a number of vias like this: -

[image]

If they need to be a tad smaller than the other vias, that shouldn't be a cause for concern.

Comment: Maybe I should use a 4layer design with the middle layers as ground?

Comment: no, you should follow Andy's advice.

Comment: @electrococuk no that's overkill. couple of vias is more than enough

Comment: @Swedgin it's not clear whether you are addressing a comment, my answer or both.

Comment: @Andyaka the comment, but I'll delete it, if it isn't clear

Comment: Ok, thank you Andy! I will just add a couple vias to the bottom ground. First need to figure  out how to place vias in a pad.

Comment: @electrococuk Really, we're only getting a really miniature excerpt from the overall design, but generally, this looks like a level of complexity and a type of components very doable on a two-sided board, if, and again, that's important, you are not hesitant to take a step back, *really* look at what you've designed. Even in this zoom-ion, we can see that there's places whre you should have avoided going to the bottom layer. No shame in that - layouting a complex board takes multiple iterations, that's totally normal. In your case, zoom out, look at which passives you could shift around and

Comment: rotate by 90° so that you can route traces beneath and between them. Then, do these component movements, and delete all the traces, and do them anew, but cleaner next time. I'm not kidding you, the first analog filter + amplifier + power board I designed, I took two days for maybe 50 components in total, and I did it **five** times, and started from scratch with nothing but a overview printout of the last iteration, just to avoid total confusion. Made a lot of difference to my ability to later on do something right on the first or second trial.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you are absolutly right. But thats going to be a prototype and I don't want to spend too much time on it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for the details I will definetly try doing it like this.

Comment: @electrococuk that board I designed was a one-off prototype for a prototype / proof of concept. It's worth it doing that. It's faster than debugging your convoluted layout later on, and it actually makes you a better layouter that gets stuff done faster the next time. I think me spending two days was a net time saver two boards later. You never unlearn the things you learn by iterating your design.

Comment: @electrococuk There is no sense in designing a prototype in anything but the best way and using the best components to suit the design i.e. design a proto with success in mind or it'll bite ya later.

Comment: Especially since that is a rather high-bandwidth opamp. You really want your ground planes to be intact, your decoupling caps to be connected to it in a via-free way, and at the very least your Vin+ and Vin- (pads 2 and 11) not to be meandered around a via. You want to read section 11 of the opamp datasheet again, especially 11.1.1 2. and 3.. The later "...recommends" statements are less binding. What worries me a bit is that you seem to be passing through your supply voltage through pins 16 through 13. That sounds like a really bad idea, noise-wise.